# Can I omit the article in this case?

Tags: definite-article, informal-language

Certain nouns, such as "baby", "Mom" or "Dad", can be used without the article "The", and I think that by doing so you give a sense of intimacy and informality. Compare, for instance, these examples:

> My mom said I should not eat that.
>
> Mom said I should not eat that.

or

> How's your baby doing?
>
> How's baby doing?

I was wondering if I could do something similar with other nouns, particularly professions, such as nanny or nurse, to produce a humorous effect.

Let's imagine this scene. A man shoots a bullet in the head of a nanny—who drops dead on the floor—and says to his friend, 'Nanny fell asleep.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find it particularly funny...

This is marginally possible, it sounds rather babyish. A child might use "nanny" as a term of address.

> Nanny, can you help me?

And as a term of address, it doesn't have an article.  In the context you give, it suggests that the man is shooting his own nanny, which makes him seem cruel and spoilt, rather than funny.

You couldn't use this of a job that isn't used as a term of address. It would be rude to say "Painter, I want this wall painted purple"

Comment: _Doctor_ and _nurse_ can be used as terms of address, but there is nothing humorous about doing so.